# Android plugin install problems in eclipse

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the ADT Plugin. I go to Help install new software in eclipse and then after selecting the development tool I get this error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found
```

EDIT
I have eclipse 3.5.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not found any solution for this. But instead of using eclipse installed with

sudo apt-get install eclipse

I downloaded it from a web page and I start that (the downloaded) eclipse, and with that version it works just fine

Comment: I had to do the same thing in Ubuntu. as it install Indigo. which seems to buggy with android development kit.

Comment: Had the same issue on Windows XP. Downloaded a fresh version of Eclipse and installed on that instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install GEF and WST first.

GEF Update Site : <s>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/</s> *(dead)*

WST Update Site : http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, run eclipse as administrator and try to instal ADT plugin again, it works.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some version mismatch. Are you using eclipse 3.6.2 or older version?

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html mentions that ADT 16.0.1 requires eclipse version 3.6 and higher.

Also, just check if you have installed/updated the latest android SDK before updating the adt. That might help in your case.

Comment: I install eclipse with sudo apt-get install eclipse and for the plugin I use this path "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

Comment: For what kind of version mismatch you are talking ? version mismatch on what ? Is there different plugin for every eclipse version ?

Comment: what is the link for the plugin for eclipse version 3.5.2 ? instead of this link "dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" what should I install ?

Answer (score 2):

In case you can't upgrade your Eclipse (like me). Use this as a local archive to install ADT 15.0.0 which supports Eclipse 3.5.

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-15.0.0.zip

Answer (score 2):

I found that using a 64bit version of eclipsed gave me that error! Try using the 32bit version and see if that fixes it! =)

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem.
I solved it by open the eclipse in the console with: sudo eclipse

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 11.10,

I downloaded Eclipse using `sudo apt-get install eclipse`

- Installed Android SDK
- Installed ADT PLugin in Eclipse (Eclipse must be started with `sudo` otherwise you will get error as mentioned by lukap)

Answer (score 1):

you just need Ecplise Helios

ADT 16.0.1 (December 2011)

Dependencies:

```
    Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6) or higher is required for ADT 16.0.1.
    ADT 16.0.1 is designed for use with SDK Tools r16. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r16 into your SDK, use the Android SDK Manager to do so.
```

taken from http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy solution for it just select option all available sites .. in the work with.. space  and select the android packages you want to install

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7, choose 'Run as Administrator' when opening eclipse. This gives eclipse the permissions it needs, and should eliminate the error. This worked for the 64-bit program.

Comment: I am on linux but sudo eclipse still doesn't helped me so see my solution above, that is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was using eclipse (helios version 3.6.2) and tried to install android SDK but i failed with abovee mentioned error.

I found the solution for this issue.

Select the "Available software sites" list

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/201102250900 (Helios) and http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios (Helios Milestone Repository)

If using galileo select the appropriate release line from avail sw site list.
'Check for Updates' (to get the Helios updates), then install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, trying to install ADT plugin, but not exactly the same.

I fixed it by going to Help > Check For Updates, and just installed current updates available, restarted Eclipse, and then tried installing ADT plugin again, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

for native install (tested on xubuntu) - please view video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCNC34BflOo&feature=player_embedded#!

shortly:

1) run eclipse from

> root-> help -> install new software -> add

name: update(S), url: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo (for 3.7.x, juno for 4.2.x)

or select in menu "work with" if path exist

2) select 'linux development'
install, all warnig/error pakages make off

3) install ADT Plugin
 after install restart eclipse and select path-to-android-sdk

4) Tape (Write) bug to our linux distributive vendor :)

Enjoy!
PS Separate install - good idea :)