# Android SDK Issues Ubuntu 10.04lts

Tags: android, eclipse

I have looked through the other questions on here, and on other forums. The answers didn't help my issue. I originally started out with 11.10 but thought there could be a bug or something that was stopping it from working. I have had the SDK and ADT working with Eclipse on both 10.04 and 11.10 so I really am at a loss as to what is going wrong.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found
```

When I ran the SDK install a second time (after uninstalling it) I noticed the following error:

```
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/home/ben/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory.
Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
```

I didn't see it there the first time and I don't know what it means or how to fix it!
Any help would be greatly appreciated, the other 'answer' I found was from the same person who asked the question, that reinstalling everything corrected the problem, I have not been so fortunate so I thought I would re-raise the query. Thank you in advance. I am using Indigo as the version, I saw elsewhere that Helios was the lowest that could use the SDK.

Gone back to 11.10 but the issue remains the same, the laptop is a Samsung R580 64bit.

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 10
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 10
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
```

Still appears when installing the SDK Tools using the following command from terminal:

```
android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're problem is entirely different than the one posted by robertly, although I'm sure you've found it using google.

You're running 64bit ubuntu and forgot to run the following command.

> apt-get install ia32-libs

The phones aren't 64bit, so there is no 64bit version of adb. You need the ia32-libs.

After this is done, open eclipse and go to 
Windows -> Android SDK Manager
then, uninstall all the tools(under tools sub folder) and reinstall them.

You should no longer get the adb error.

Source:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting

Solution #2 - I had to do this because sudo apt-get remove eclipse didn't remove it completely and it still cause errors. Doing all of this, combined with the step above solved my problem the other night.

Delete eclipse, android folders
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
sudo update-alternatives --config java
Reinstall eclipse 3.7.1, android-sdk-linux folder
Proceed with normal installation.

Comment: Going to try that now, I didn't think about the 32-64bit, completely overlooked that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have updated the initial question (new stuff is at the bottom). Still getting the same error after running "sudo apt-get install ia32-libs" which installed without error.

Comment: You have an outdated version of eclipse. You need 3.6.2 minimum.
Missing Requirement: 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2'

Did you do sudo apt-get install eclipse? In that event, you get version 3.5.2. Head over to eclipse.org and get the latest version.

Comment: Ah right okay then, do you know a good link or how to install Eclipse from tgz as I tried before but couldn't get it to work?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ Download Eclipse Classic 3.7.1 Extract the eclipse folder to a directory of your choosing and double click the "eclipse" file in the folder.

Comment: Thanks, however, when installing the SDK again. I still got the same error "Stopping ADB server failed (code 1)".

Comment: I have followed everything you said up to and including the installing Eclipse. However, when I removed it last time it said it wasn't installed. Does double clicking the eclipse file in the Eclipse folder actually install it? Also, when I execute the SDK manager from terminal to install it I get four warnings saying "unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap" "

Comment: When you double click the eclipse file, it should open eclipse and run it. I didn't install using the SDK manager. I just went to Windows > Android SDK Manager. After doing the ADT Plugin stuff in Help > Install New Software...

Comment: Aha yet another issue, I've got the latest version of Eclipse, running looking for SDK Manager, but can't see it in the tool bar of WINDOW, or the others.

Comment: You need to install the ADT Plugin first. That's why you got the 2 errors most likely. http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Comment: Still downloading the SDK files through the SDK manager, it's thrown up no errors. So, I'll go with you're a saviour! Thanks a lot, baffled my lecture(s) and Linux nuts, nice one!

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue. sudo apt-get install eclipse will install an old version of eclipse, but it doesn't seem to go away, even after sudo apt-get remove eclipse. So I eventually found the autoremove command, and then I didn't have the java JRE because it removed everything associated with eclipse. Then I reinstalled JRE and eclipse and it worked :O lol

Answer (score 1):

Head on over here, it looks to be the same problem, but with a different package. 
[Eclipse Indigo - Cannot install Android ADT Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482268/eclipse-indigo-cannot-install-android-adt-plugin)

This is assuming you haven't seen that yet. If you are still having problems, I can look into it further for you.

Comment: Edited my initial post, Indigo is what I am using.

Comment: Thank you, I had seen it but re-tried twice anyway, still the same issue. Could it be the SDK not installing properly when I run the SDK Manager?

Comment: I just want to make sure, but did you try the second answer in that post:   Go to Help->Install Software
Click on "Available Software Sites"
Click on Add: Name: "Helios" Location: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios"
Try to install Android Development Tools

Comment: If you did, then I will check with the Android SDK team about it further, they might know more.

Comment: I didn't because I am running Indigo, or doesn't that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it might. I think it might be looking for dependencies during installation. The package it is looking for is a helios package.

Comment: Still saying the same thing, thank you anyway. This is really annoying. Is there anything you can think of that I may need to install other than JDK (which I've done) in order to get the SDK Manager to properly install. That is the only thing I can think of that would be hindering it considering the content of the error message, thanks.

Comment: The only other thing I might suggest is to download indigo again from eclipse.org, unzip it into another directory, and try again with that instance. It does not look like a JDK error.

Comment: I re-edited my initial post, I saw an SDK error when I re-ran the SDK Manager, perhaps it is linked to that?

Comment: THat is odd. What SDK tools version are you running? Also, what ADT do you have and what ADT version are you trying to install? adb was moved a while ago, so it looks like you have an ADT version that is newer than your SDK tools version, so it is looking for adb in the wrong place.

Comment: Literally, with the set up I have now, just installed 10.04lts, installed JDK (newest one), eclipse from terminal (sudo apt-get eclipse) and downloaded the newest SDK from Android.google then moved the tgz and unzipped it with terminal. Installed it all several times before, no problem, even resorted to following youtube.com/watch?v=t8UREMU-wSU

Comment: This thread seems to suggest that installing with apt-get doesn't work and downloading directly from eclipse.org does. Please try that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629294/android-plugin-install-problems-in-eclipse

Comment: Just installed Galileo manually, still get the same error. I think it is to do with the SDK installer. But I am not sure what's wrong.