# error in android sdk manager log while installing android

Tags: android, android-emulator

while installing i got a message "Stopping ADB server failed (code -1)." in Android sdk manager log every time. is this the reason i am unable to install adt plugin in eclipse?? i am doing all over again. i have formatted my pc for only for this.plz help.

the whole message of log is here:

Found XOOM, Android API 11, revision 2
Fetching URL: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Validate XML: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Parse XML:
  Found GALAXY Tab, Android API 8, revision 1
Fetching URL: 
Validate XML: 
Parse XML:
  Found EDK 2.0, Android API 10, revision 2
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11`enter code here`
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812329/android-sdk-issues-ubuntu-10-04lts and the answers given in there.

Answer (score 1):

Which Operating system you are using....???

System Requirements -
Currently the following operating systems are supported:

1. Windows XP or Vista
2. Mac OS X 10.4.8 or later (x86 only)
3. Linux (tested on Linux Ubuntu Dapper Drake)