# Install android adt in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to install android in eclipse to develop apps on my ubuntu setup.

I get the following error though:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 
(com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is? I have tried using the url and download the zip manually in eclipse under add new software.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629294/android-plugin-install-problems-in-eclipse might help

Answer (score 0):

During installation, there's an error about requiring org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui. How do I fix that?

The Google Plugin for Eclipse depends on other specific Eclipse components, such as WST. Your installation of Eclipse may not yet include all of them, but they can be easily installed by following these instructions. Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Select Help > Install New Software...
Click the link for Available Software Sites.
Ensure there is an update site named Juno. If this is not present, click Add... and enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno for the Location.
Now go through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and install the plugin's dependencies.

Filter for wst and install all those. Restart Eclipse and then you can install the adt plugins.

Comment: If you lowercase, that Juno on the URL (so that it's http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno) you don't get a 404, and everything works as expected.

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry. Glad it worked for you Herm. I'll edit the link

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
When installing ADT through Eclipse just make sure you have checked: Contact all update sites during install to find required software. That helped me.

Also try to update eclipse (Help -> Check for updates)

Solution is: check the contact all update sites ...

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. If you need the ADT version 20.0.0 then install it manually (from a ZIP archive) as described [here](http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#InstallingADT) and download it from here: http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-20.0.0.zip

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Intsalling Android ADB on Eclipse JUNO Windows7PRO.

These steps worked for me:
1- go to "help" - "install new software"
2- inserert a new path called AndroidADT https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3- check the box "Contact all update sites during install to find required software". 
4- select all the 6 android components
5- download, restar eclipse, update the adt then... enjoy!!!